# C++11 Base constructor delegating/forwarding to derived class with "using" keyword

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, using, default-constructor

```
struct B {
  B () {}
  B(int i) {}
};

struct D : B {
  using B::B;  // <--- new C++11 feature
};

D d1; // ok
D d2(3); // ok
```

Now, if I add a new constructor  inside the body of `struct D`, such as:

```
struct D : B {
  using B::B;
  D(const char* pc) {}  // <--- added
};
```

then `D d1;` starts giving compiler error([ideone](http://ideone.com/JCUPka) is not upgraded yet, I am using g++ 4.8.0)? However `D d2(3);` still works.

Why the default constructor is discounted when adding a new constructor inside `struct D`?

Comment: It looks like the Standard specifies this behaviour: "For each non-template constructor in the candidate set of inherited constructors **other than a constructor having no parameters or a copy/move constructor having a single parameter**, a constructor is implicitly declared [...]" [class.inhctor]/3 Why? Don't know..

Comment: Note that the demo you're linking to doesn't support inherited constructors at all. You could try [here](http://liveworkspace.org/), but it seems to be down at the moment.

Comment: @DyP, in the code snippet you haven't added the new `D(const char*)` constructor

Comment: @iammilind m( you're right..

Comment: @iammilind Can't post the link to the live example of the "correct" version, link is too long for a comment.... :(

Comment: @MikeSeymour, you are correct, ideone is not upgraded yet, however I am using 4.8.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between

```
struct D : B {
 using B::B;
 D(const char* pc) {}  // <--- added
};
```

versus

```
struct D : B {
 using B::B;
};
```

In the second case, compiler auto-generate the default "D(){}" constructor for you. But if you create your own constructor for D, then the default "D(){}" is not available anymore. Sure you have inherited B's default constructor, but that doesn't tell the compiler how to construct D by default.

Comment: Do you have any clue _why_ the default ctor is not inherited?

Comment: Yes, as I stated in my comment to the OP, only non-default non-copy non-move ctors are/can be inherited.

Comment: @DyP As a guess?  Because you can already inherit the default ctor via `D() = default;`.  For copy/move, having `D(B const&)` and `D(B&&)` might be overly error-prone.

Comment: I might add another guess: If the default ctor was inherited by `using B::B;`, you couldn't inherit just the non-default ctors of `B` w/o also inheriting the default ctor. The default ctor isn't implicitly declared if there's a user-defined ctor as this would be error-prone, this also applies here.